# How watchkit app communicate with iphone parent application in ios

Tags: ios, watchkit, xcode-6.2

HI i want to implement sample application on watch kit app. i want to show some information of parent application , which is running in iphone, now i want to get data in watch kit app from preform action from button click on watch kit . i have used delegate method for background communication with extension app but   Am getting same error when i print error in

```
[InterfaceController openParentApplication:dict reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"%@",[replyInfo objectForKey:@"Key"]); 
    NSLog(@"error:-%@",[error description]);
}
```

Getting the Error ....

```
Error: Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 "The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]" UserInfo=0x7f8603227730 {NSLocalizedDescription=The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]}
```

please suggest how can i get data in watch app from extention app.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Go to Appdelegate.m and implement the application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply: method

Comment: yes I have implement code in  application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply method in appdelegate method  but still i am getting same error and in debug condition reach in this handler method

Comment: Have you pass sth to watch app by the reply block?

Comment: may i know sth means. and how can we write in reply block please suggest

Comment: YES i am pass data information in reply block and return dictnory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my watch app, I want to setup my mapview, so I ask my app for a location.

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    // Configure interface objects here.
    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:@{} reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
        if (replyInfo) {

            [self.map setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([replyInfo[@"lat"] doubleValue], [replyInfo[@"lon"] doubleValue]), MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05))];
        }
    }];
}
```

Then I put back location from my app delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    reply(@{@"lat": @"22.3175899",@"lon": @"114.2212058"});
}
```

Comment: and in my app i am doing this type- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
{
    [self GetWordsFromApplication:userInfo andreply:reply];
}

Comment: I doubt that the reply block is not been called.

Comment: so please can you suggest more about reply block

Comment: Is your GetWordsFromApplication:andreplay being called?

Comment: NO , Bebug is not come in this method , also not come in handler method.

Comment: Then you need fix it and call reply()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73071/discussion-between-jaydev-and-horst).